# Windows 10 'task scheduler ' does not run a functioning program in Windows XP compatibility mode

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, compatibility, task-scheduler

Windows 10 task scheduler does not run a functioning program that is set for compatibility mode for Windows XP.

For example, when the program is set to compatibility mode for Windows XP and the program `.exe` is clicked on, the program functions as normal.  Then - if I setup  'Task Scheduler' to run this program and create a shortcut to the task to run the program it shows the splash screen for the program then fails to start and ceases.

I have tried the 'configure for' different operating systems in 'task scheduler' but there is no Windows XP option there. This (USING TASK SCHEDULER) is all done to avoid 'User Account Control' nag box that pops up when starting the program. Because shutting off 'user account control' is a very bad decision for the security of a windows 10 computer .

Is there a work around or a solution for this issue?

Comment: Can you post an example XML file for this configuration?